# Blender 2.8 - Keyboard not detected

Tags: hardware

I'm trying out the latest Blender 2.8 beta (tried both 15th and 16th of December) and I can't get Blender to detect my keyboard. No key works. If I look in the user prefs/input it's completely empty. Is this a known bug or am I missing something? It all works without problems in 2.79.

There's an error when starting in command line:

```
C:\>D:\blender-2.80.0-git.4488056f3d9-windows64\blender.exe
    Read prefs: C:\Users\Simon\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.80\config\userpref.blend
    found bundled python: D:\blender-2.80.0-git.4488056f3d9-windows64\2.80\python
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "D:\blender-2.80.0-git.4488056f3d9-windows64\2.80\scripts\modules\addon_utils.py", line 351, in enable
        mod = __import__(module_name)
      File "D:\blender-2.80.0-git.4488056f3d9-windows64\2.80\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
        from .io.com.gltf2_io_debug import Log
      File "D:\blender-2.80.0-git.4488056f3d9-windows64\2.80\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\io\com\gltf2_io_debug.py", line 20, in <module>
        import logging
      File "D:\blender-2.80.0-git.4488056f3d9-windows64\2.80\python\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
        import sys, os, time, io, traceback, warnings, weakref, collections.abc
      File "D:\blender-2.80.0-git.4488056f3d9-windows64\2.80\python\lib\traceback.py", line 5, in <module>
        import linecache
      File "D:\blender-2.80.0-git.4488056f3d9-windows64\2.80\python\lib\linecache.py", line 11, in <module>
        import tokenize
      File "D:\blender-2.80.0-git.4488056f3d9-windows64\2.80\python\lib\tokenize.py", line 33, in <module>
        import re
      File "D:\blender-2.80.0-git.4488056f3d9-windows64\2.80\python\lib\re.py", line 122, in <module>
        import enum
    ImportError: bad magic number in 'enum': b'\x03\xf3\r\n'

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "D:\blender-2.80.0-git.4488056f3d9-windows64\2.80\scripts\modules\bpy\__init__.py", line 81, in <module>
        main()
      File "D:\blender-2.80.0-git.4488056f3d9-windows64\2.80\scripts\modules\bpy\__init__.py", line 78, in main
        utils.load_scripts()
      File "D:\blender-2.80.0-git.4488056f3d9-windows64\2.80\scripts\modules\bpy\utils\__init__.py", line 273, in load_scripts
        _initialize()
      File "D:\blender-2.80.0-git.4488056f3d9-windows64\2.80\scripts\modules\addon_utils.py", line 47, in _initialize
        enable(addon.module)
      File "D:\blender-2.80.0-git.4488056f3d9-windows64\2.80\scripts\modules\addon_utils.py", line 359, in enable
        handle_error(ex)
      File "D:\blender-2.80.0-git.4488056f3d9-windows64\2.80\scripts\modules\addon_utils.py", line 299, in handle_error
        import traceback
      File "D:\blender-2.80.0-git.4488056f3d9-windows64\2.80\python\lib\traceback.py", line 5, in <module>
        import linecache
      File "D:\blender-2.80.0-git.4488056f3d9-windows64\2.80\python\lib\linecache.py", line 11, in <module>
        import tokenize
      File "D:\blender-2.80.0-git.4488056f3d9-windows64\2.80\python\lib\tokenize.py", line 33, in <module>
        import re
      File "D:\blender-2.80.0-git.4488056f3d9-windows64\2.80\python\lib\re.py", line 122, in <module>
        import enum
    ImportError: bad magic number in 'enum': b'\x03\xf3\r\n'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "D:\blender-2.80.0-git.4488056f3d9-windows64\2.80\scripts\modules\bpy\utils\__init__.py", line 186, in register_module_call
        register()
      File "D:\blender-2.80.0-git.4488056f3d9-windows64\2.80\scripts\startup\bl_operators\__init__.py", line 69, in register
        register_class(cls)
    ValueError: register_class(...): already registered as a subclass

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "D:\blender-2.80.0-git.4488056f3d9-windows64\2.80\scripts\modules\bpy\__init__.py", line 81, in <module>
        main()
      File "D:\blender-2.80.0-git.4488056f3d9-windows64\2.80\scripts\modules\bpy\__init__.py", line 78, in main
        utils.load_scripts()
      File "D:\blender-2.80.0-git.4488056f3d9-windows64\2.80\scripts\modules\bpy\utils\__init__.py", line 261, in load_scripts
        test_register(mod)
      File "D:\blender-2.80.0-git.4488056f3d9-windows64\2.80\scripts\modules\bpy\utils\__init__.py", line 228, in test_register
        register_module_call(mod)
      File "D:\blender-2.80.0-git.4488056f3d9-windows64\2.80\scripts\modules\bpy\utils\__init__.py", line 188, in register_module_call
        import traceback
      File "D:\blender-2.80.0-git.4488056f3d9-windows64\2.80\python\lib\traceback.py", line 5, in <module>
        import linecache
      File "D:\blender-2.80.0-git.4488056f3d9-windows64\2.80\python\lib\linecache.py", line 11, in <module>
        import tokenize
      File "D:\blender-2.80.0-git.4488056f3d9-windows64\2.80\python\lib\tokenize.py", line 33, in <module>
        import re
      File "D:\blender-2.80.0-git.4488056f3d9-windows64\2.80\python\lib\re.py", line 122, in <module>
        import enum
    ImportError: bad magic number in 'enum': b'\x03\xf3\r\n'

    location: <unknown location>:-1

    location: <unknown location>:-1
    Keymap: '3D View Tool: Select Box' not found for tool 'Select Box'
```

Comment: I'm on Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

After compiling 2.80 in Linux I had similar problem, no keys were working and this error was repeated infinitely:

```
Keymap: '3D View Tool: Select Box' not found for tool 'Select Box'
```

By googling this message I have found you question. I solved the issue by removing `~/.config/blender/2.80` - after this everything worked.

It was a bit strange that my own build did not work with my existing user preferences, since daily builds worked just fine with them, but I guess something was wrong, since after recreating them and enabling similar set of addons everything works just fine.

In non-Linux OSes path to user preferences is much longer:

```
Windows Vista/7/8/10: C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender
Windows XP: C:\Documents and Settings\username\Application Data\Blender Foundation\Blender
Mac OS X: /Users/{user}/Library/Application Support/Blender
```

Navigate there and try to remove or rename 2.80 folder.

Comment: On every OS since Windows XP, you simply can replace the long path to "Roaming" with "%AppData%". This will take you directly to the currently logged-on user's Roaming profile.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue and got this response on the Blender website.

It looks like conflicting settings with some old version.

Try the Blender zipped version.

[image]

Or clean uninstall old blender files

Load Factory Settings & Save Startup File Also Edit -> Preferences Load Factory Setting & Save

[image]

Then try a new project.

For a smooth Blender experience, update your graphics drivers to the latest version from the official site.

Comment: If this works, or if you've found another solution please update.